# Daphne Docker Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yourproject'

Tags: python, django, docker, daphne

When I try to run daphne in docker I have this problem. I have no idea to fix it :)

I use docker compose to build it.
my project
-nginx
-redis
-daphne
-django channels

```
~/pyprj/Django# docker logs 3517329befc9
New pypi version: 0.2.0.2 (current: 0.1.8.7) | pip install -U g4f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Django/gptweb/gptweb/asgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/asgi.py", line 12, in get_asgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yourproject'
```

this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
 redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - /gptweb/redis/data:/data
 django:
    build: ./gptweb
    command: sh -c "gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=gptweb.settings gptweb.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8001"
    volumes:
     - ./gptweb:/gptweb
     - static_data:/gptweb/chat/static
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
      - 8002:8002
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./env.dev
 nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_data:/var/www/html/static
 daphne:
    build:
      context: ./gptweb
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.daphne
    command: 'sh -c "daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8002  gptweb.asgi:application"'
    restart: always
volumes:
  static_data:
```

This is my daphne docker file
Dockerfile.daphne

```
WORKDIR /Django/gptweb

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
 PYTHONBUFFERED=1


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

### I tried run daphne in guinicorn container but it does not work. Also I did this without supervisor

**SOLVED**
**I just changed the os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourproject.settings') to os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gptweb.settings') And it's now working. I run daphne separatly from guinicorn image**

Comment: can you show the `ASGI.py`? It's probably not setting the environment variable right. When you copy something from docs - read more closely. It often tells you which variables to change according to your project. How do you expect daphne to run if you are only executing the gunicorn command?

Comment: Thank you, I just changed the os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourproject.settings') to os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gptweb.settings') And it's now working. I run daphne separatly from guinicorn image

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourproject.settings') to os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gptweb.settings') And it's now working. I run daphne separatly from guinicorn image